# What is the meaning of "Neanderthals on a day pass"?

Tags: american-english, slang, speech, humor

Said as some sort of an insult I guess.

Comment: Where did you see/hear this phrase?

Comment: This is not a well-known expression.  So we need more context to tell what it means.

Comment: Of course, "Neanderthal" is term often used to imply that the person being described is crude and uncivilized.

Comment: @GEdgar not much context to it really, a guy expresses his opinion on a group of people he seems to not like. neanderthals on its own is kind of an insult already.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you understand it already... Would imagine it's implying that not only are said folks 'Neanderthals' (an unenlightened or ignorant person; barbarian. dictionary.com) they are also on a so-called 'day pass.'

Since this is an insult, 'day pass' is probably not being used to mean "a ticket that allows entry for a single day."

As an insult, this term means (according to an Urban Dictionary post from 2007)

> A person who looks, acts, speaks or dresses as if they belong in a mental institution and have been let out for the day.

So pair those two together and you have a nice little burn.

Comment: I don't think ***day pass*** here means "a ticket that allows entry for a single day". More likely the allusion is to a ***prisoner*** (or other "forced resident") being ***allowed out*** for a single day (compare soldiers being allowed to leave the barracks for a couple of days on a ***weekend pass***).

Comment: @fumblefingers Yes... I also don't think that's how it's being used. Since I literally said that in my post. "Since this is an insult,  'day pass' is not being used to mean, 'A ticket that allows entry for a single day.'"

Comment: oops - I missed *...probably **not...*** in your answer! I'll leave the comment though, since yours straightens things out anyway.

Comment: @Lemons i find it weird the question is closed for not being clear enough while it is appearently clear enough for this complete answer